# C# with libvlc.dll

Tags: c#, wrapper, vlc, libvlc

Actually, I'm not a C# programmer, but in the part of project, I needed to play RTSP stream in C# via libvlc.

After googled my problem, I found this - working - example : http://libvlcnet.sourceforge.net/ and videolan.org forum's.

But all of these are too complicated to understand for me.

My program is supposed to be just playing RTSP stream in a full screen.

Also, I can not add libvlc.dll into my project by using add reference. It gives an error. Therefore, I cannot create basic media player.

Basicly, what should I do ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to sit down, study the libraries and try to understand them.

Comment: I think that I understand the wrapper's logic and purpose of this, also I have a complete control over libvlc's library. My main problem is I cannot add libvlc.dll as a reference into my project but sample projects can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Create a lib and link against it: http://wiki.videolan.org/GenerateLibFromDll